# Internet explorer 10 word-break not working

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

I want the text to wrap accordingly to the width of the table if it is changed. My CSS works everywhere (Firefox, Chrome, even other versions of IE) except for IE 10.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody class="tBody">
      <tr>
       <td>
          <span class="spanClass">
             <img src="image.png">
              <a href="">This is a verrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrryyyyy long
                      text that doesnt work like I want it to. I hate IE.
              </a>
           </span>
         </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.container {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  display: inline-table;
  word-wrap: break-word; 
  word-break: break-all;
 }

 table {
  width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
 }

.spanClass {
  display: inline-flex;
 }
```

Ive noticed the `.spanClass` rule may be interfering with what I want, but I need that rule to keep the `<img>` and `<a>` elements aligned properly in other browsers.

Answer (score 7):

You can use below css instead of yours:

```
.spanClass {
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
 }
```

Comment: This solution did not solve the problem. I experienced the same problem with IE10 not automatically breaking the text line like chrome. A quick search in caniuse shows that the value `break-word` is not supported in IE10 
https://caniuse.com/#search=break-word

Answer (score 5):

IE10 is a browser that is no longer supported and Microsoft do not invest time in developing new features or adapting it to updating technologies(JS, CSS etc...).

To currently resolve your issue you can give the container that holds the text a fixed `width` in pixels. IE10 would then remove any overflowing-x content to the next line. This is the best you can achieve if needed to support IE10. You can see that IE10 does not respect the `word-break` value in pic attached:
[image]

Link to check:
https://caniuse.com/#search=break-word

In my case for example(in which I was required to support a certain item card container inner text overflowing on the x axis(horizontally) - what I did is give `width: 120px;` and was able to make IE10 respect this width and break the sentence.